# toTitleCase while preserving in-word upperCasing

Tags: c#, string

I'm using reflection to invoke methods and access properties in C#.  The names of these properties and and methods have already been declared (in strings from a certain data source), but not in a 'method friendly' manner.

For example, a particular object has the property "HasAModifiedShortStyle"
At runtime I don't know this. I know I'm looking for a property described with "has a modified ShortStyle".

So the easy thing is to convert to TitleCase using

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.TextInfo)
```

and replace " " with "".

This works fine, but the TextInfo.ToTitleCase() changes "ShortStyle" to "Shortstyle". That lower case 's' causes me to not find the propertyName.
For reference, I'm accessing the property with

```
currentObjectValue.GetType().GetProperty(propertyName);
```

Is there an easy way to convert to TitleCase while preserving the in-word capitilization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this approach?

```
currentObjectValue.GetType().GetProperties().FirstOrDefault(propInfo => propInfo.Name.Equals("Shortstyle", StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase));
```

Comment: Yup, while Daniel's answer does what's needed, all the other case related issues are easily solved with this answer.

Answer (score 1):

Just use this for every word in your description:

```
yourString[0].ToString().ToUpper() + yourString.Substring(1)
```

Comment: Thanks, needed something uncomplicated to implement. Ran into other issues like phrases "counter-proceeding" needing to become "CounterProceeding" but will have to maybe look at those separately. This would be a lot easier if my inputs only had letters!

Answer (score 0):

This will split the description string into individual words, capitalize the first letter, and then join them back into a single string:

```
string s = "has a modified ShortStyle";
propName = string.Join(string.Empty, 
                       (from word in s.Split(' ')
                        select word.Substring(0, 1).ToUpper() + word.Substring(1)).ToArray());
```